# Vertical align text to a box next to it

Tags: latex, pandoc

In the output below, I'm trying to align *Author* with the top of the box next to it. I've tried a couple of different boxes and whatnot, but I can't get it to align properly.

[image: Output]

Here's the code:

```
\mbox{
Author
}
\fbox{\begin{minipage}[c]{12cm}
\medskip
$for(author)$
    $author.name$\\$if(author.title)$\emph{$author.title$}\\$endif$$if(author.company)$$author.company$$endif$
    \par\medskip
$endfor$
\medskip
\end{minipage}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the entire construction inside a `tabular`, and then also use a `[t]`op-aligned `tabular` for the framed box construction:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l | l |}
  \cline{2-2}
  Author & \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}p{12cm}@{}}
    Jack Appleseed \\
    \emph{Marketing Manager} \\
    Unimaginitive Solutions \\ \\
    John Appleseed \\
    \emph{Business Development Manager} \\
    Unimaginitive Solutions \\
  \end{tabular} \\
  \cline{2-2}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

I'm assuming you can use the following Pandoc construction (I haven't used Pandoc):

```
\begin{tabular}{l | l |}
  \cline{2-2}
  Author & \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}p{12cm}@{}}
    $for(author)$
      $author.name$ \\ $if(author.title)$\emph{$author.title$} \\ $endif$ $if(author.company)$ $author.company$ \\ $endif$
    $endfor$
  \end{tabular} \\
  \cline{2-2}
\end{tabular}
```